# Creating a box-plot like scatter-plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, boxplot

Is there any (simple or complex) way to recreate this plot in matplotlib?

[image: box-plot like scatter-plot]

I've tried plotting it using a scatter plot with two different x-values, while adding a small random number to it, but obviously it didn't produce the nice "ordered" effect seen above.

Comment: There's a package built on top of matplotlib call beeswarm that positions the points as shown:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgymrek/pybeeswarm/blob/master/beeswarm_example.ipynb

Comment: @PaulH Thanks, I didn't even know the plot's name so it was hard searching for it. You can put it as an Answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a package built on top of `matplotlib` called [beeswarm](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgymrek/pybeeswarm/blob/master/beeswarm_example.ipynb) that positions the points as requested.